# How does Pig Pass Data from First Job and its next Job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig, hdfs, distributed

As we all know, Apache Pig is a data flow language. If I write a Pig Script and the Pig decides to split and run two or more jobs to execute the task in hand, so  How does Pig Store the data which it passes from job1 to job 2. ???!!

*I read the Pig documentation which says* :-

"**Pig allocates a fix amount of memory to store bags and spills to disk as soon as the memory limit is reached. This is very similar to how Hadoop decides when to spill data accumulated by the combiner.**"

*(url : http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/perf.html#memory-management)*

So Does Pig has a writer which stores the output of an intermediate job in Memory / RAM for better performance (spill to disk if required) and then if PIG has implemented a Reader which reads the data directly from memory to pass that data to the next Job for Processing???

In Mapreduce, we write the entire data to disk and then read it again for the next job to start.

Does Pig has a upper hand here, by implementing readers and writers which writes in RAM/memory (spill if required) and reads from RAM (and disk if required) for better Performance.

Kindly share your expertise/ views on the highlighted comment from the PIG documentation as to what does it actually mean or is stating otherwise.

Thanks in Advance,
Cheers :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If pig script has multiple jobs,than output of each job is written into a temporary folder in HDFS, which is defined by pig.temp.dir (default is /tmp). See [Pig Docs](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.13.0/start.html) "Storing Intermediate Results". Also while running script do `hadoop fs -ls /tmp/pig*`, sometimes when jobs are interrupted, these folders are not cleaned up and need to be freed manually.

The spilling of the bags refers to what happens in the Mapper stage and there is not RAM communication between MR jobs.

Comment: hey that was quite a clean answer to my question and I understood it well. Can you provide any supporting documents as well , which actually backs the point, I have been looking out for this and was not able to find one.

Comment: Click on the "Pig Docs" link in my answer and search for "Storing Intermediate Results. Also google for Hadoop shared nothing architecture to see that in MR RAM is not used to share information, it can be done only via files.